# SF movie involving robot-controlling antagonist

Tags: story-identification

This movie has puzzled me for years. The problem is that I have seen only pieces of it on TV.

The movie was probably shot before or within a few years of 2000. Near-future setting. Simple robots are extensively used. The protagonist is a detective or some kind of law enforcement officer. The antagonist controls and uses numerous spider-like robots. In one scene, early in the movie I think, the protagonist goes into house to eliminate a simple rogue household robot. The rogue robot is armed with handgun. I think the protagonist uses a laser weapon but I am not sure.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088024/

Comment: Beat me by *that* much.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Gotta be quick around here. A day late and a dollar short, as my old man never said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Runaway](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088024/), starring Tom Selleck

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_(1984_film)):

> The film is set in the near future, where robots are commonplace--a
> part of everyday life like any other electrical appliance--and are
> just as prone to malfunctions. But when a robot malfunctions, it could
> pose a threat to people or property. Such robots are known as
> "runaways." Since they are more dangerous than the average machine,
> they are handled by a division of the police trained in robotics. The
> "runaway" squad, however, is treated as an easy and unexciting
> assignment and often ridiculed.