# Sci-fi film/TV show in which a bullet can chase people like a missile

Tags: story-identification, movie

Date: 1990s?

Remembered scene (not sure):

1. One bullet chases and kills a person in a street. The bullet can change direction like a missile and can even turn 180 degrees. The scene has a cool color.
2. In a room, some guy blinks his eye or gazes toward some camera-like device on the roof, which triggers something bad (like an explosion?).
3. Not even sure 1 and 2 are indeed from the same film, only have a strong feeling that they are linked.

Online search indicates *The Fifth Element*, but the color is warm and the missile-bullet scene has a lot of bullets and is not on a street.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, did you watch it on TV or online? If on TV, then in which country and language?

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121870/sf-movie-involving-robot-controlling-antagonist/121871#121871 - Runaway starring Tom Selleck - [Bullet scene](https://youtu.be/S5YOiaBq3KI)

Comment: Much later than 1990 but perhaps [wanted](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0493464/) ? Curving bullets is a major plot point.

Comment: My first thought was *Logan's Run* with the Seeker bullet, but I couldn't find corresponding footage.

Comment: My first thought (which I'm absolutely sure is wrong) is Who Framed Roger Rabbit.

Comment: @Valorum  Re: Closing... The Answer is the same, but the question is different. Should it still be closed? This Question is looking for the movie with the Tracking Bullet. That is not even mentioned in the Referenced question. (Same with controlling the bomb by blinking)

Comment: @NJohnny - Yes, where the answer to a Story-ID question is the confirmed to be the same property, we mark them as duplicates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Going by memory you're probably remembering the 1984 Tom Selleck movie [*Runaway*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0088024/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0).

The villain has advanced robots which, along with typical spider robots and the like, include a gun that fires intelligent "bullets" that can track and follow a target.

[image: Bullet point of view shot chasing a police officer]

In the following scene we see bullets turn corners multiple times, fly through a pipe, and do a couple of 180s:

There's another scene where the smart bullets are fired late in the movie; it's night in those scenes so the colour is cooler.

In this scene Luther, the villain, looks up and blinks twice to trigger a smoke-bomb robot:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heMboVN12r0 might have footage (can't watch it here).

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for the link to the scene.

Answer (score 6):

This could be a partial match to "[Wanted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanted_(2008_film))" a 2008 film starring Angelina Jolie, Morgan Freeman and James McAvoy. In this movie McAvoy's character (Wesley) is the son of a high ranking assassin, and, unbeknownst to him, has inherited his father's skills. When his father is killed, it is revealed to Wesley that the father was an assassin and his killer is also after Wesley. Wesley is then trained and becomes an expert assassin, using his skills to avenge his father's death and bring down the ancient assassin organization.

What makes this a partial match:

Cool (blue, green, grey) colours are used throughout the movie, particularly in the scenes where Wesley is under training and in the assassin base.

The assassins are trained to "curve" bullets around obstacles to reach targets around corners.

One of the climactic scenes in the movie uses a multi-stage bullet fired from a long way away, that seems to chase the target (from memory, this may be incorrect).

Part of the climactic scene involves the target looking at something, which is the key for the hero to fire the multi-stage bullet.

Comment: Feels weird to leave Angelina Jolie out of the billing on this, seeing as she was on very-nearly-all of the promotional material, and is at least as important a character as Morgan Freeman.

Comment: @KRyan quite right - I had forgotten she was in it, I was going entirely off memory. I'll add her in.

Comment: I can’t forget this movie because I nearly fell out of my chair at the movie theater, I was laughing so hard at the claim that “It’s binary!”